# How can I return success to AngularJS after successful Java rest login?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

```js
app.register.factory('AuthenticationService', ['Base64','$http','$cookieStore','$rootScope','$timeout',
                                                function(Base64,$http,$cookieStore,$rootScope,$timeout){
  var service = {};
  
  service.Login= function(username,password,callback) {
   
   var encodedString = 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password);
   var baseUrl = "https://localhost:450/rest/";
   $http({
    method:'POST',
    url:baseUrl + 'dns/loginResource',
    data:encodedString,
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        
   }).success(function(response) {
    
    callback(response);
   });
```

I have this code in frontend side which successfully sends credentials to Path

```
@Path("/dns/loginResource")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String queryAuthenticationData(@FormParam("username") String USER_NAME, @FormParam("password") String PASS_WORD)
{


    Password HashPass = new Password();
    try {
        //PASS_WORD=HashPass.getSaltedHash(PASS_WORD);
        Login log = new Login(USER_NAME,PASS_WORD);
        ResultSet UserDetailsSet;
        System.out.println("queryAuthenticationData metodu içinde...");
        UserDetailsSet = log.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "";

}
```

And this code also works, it login and return ResultSet to UserDetailsSet.

My Question is how can I communicate with frontend code that logs in successfully(so response be true).
Also How can i send resultset information which consist of userid, username, password to AngularJS code.

Comment: You can send a response object which will have encrypted user details and and status code. For Eg- 200 status code for Success

Comment: Can you give a example. I am new in front-side development

Comment: return "success" from queryAuthenticationData, or any object. you can get that in the $http success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with `HTTP` status codes, see list of all available statuses at http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html.

From your front-end application, check the request response `HTTP` status code to handle the different scenarios (ex. a valid authentication request would be respond with a `200 OK` status, upon a invalid request you could respond with a `401 Unauthorized` status).

The `HTTP status responses` can be set using :

```
 // respond with 200 OK
 return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

 // respond with other status
 return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
```